# Why accessing Keys Values in dictionary in python like this is not working

Tags: python-3.x, function, dictionary, key-value

Is not both are right?

```
def report():
"""It prints the value of each resource"""

    print(f"resources['water']: {resources['water']}")
    print(f"resources['milk']: {resources['milk']}")
    print(f"resources['coffee']: {resources['coffee']}")
    print(f"resources['money']: {resources['money']}")
 

             vs

    print(f"resources{['water']}")
    print(f"resources{['milk']}")
    print(f"resources{['coffee']}")
    print(f"resources{['money']}")
```

hi i tried to acess the dictionary values within the function but it isnot working.I questioned GPT & it spit out the first version which miraculously worked but i couldnot figure out why my version didnot work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What does your ```resources``` dictionary look like?

Comment: resources = {
    "water": 300,
    "milk": 200,
    "coffee": 100,
}

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because the syntax of

```
 print(f"resources{['money']}")
```

is wrong. `['money']` is an array of a single value, not a reference to the dictionary. You should put {} around the whole variable.

Let me break it down:

```
some_variable = 1
f"sometext {some_variable}" # should print "sometext 1
```

now the same with dict values:

```
some_variable = resources['water']
f"sometext {some_variable}"
```

now injecting your dict value directly into the string:

```
f"sometext {resources['water']}"
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying,(this is what happens when you don't take a break for too long:)).
it should have been like this:
  print(f"{resources['water']}")